# Ubuntu battery life on Macbook Air (6,2) - 14.04 (good) vs 16.04 and 18.04 (kinda bad)

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, power-management, battery, macbook-air

**14.04:**

When I initially installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my 6,2 MacBook Air, I was flabbergasted by the reported (and actual) battery life:

- OS X reported ~12 hours
- Ubuntu 14.04 reported ~14 hours (yes, my face was like "whaat!" when I saw it, but this was indeed the case.)

After ~2 years, Ubuntu settled at around 8hrs of battery autonomy. No tweaking, no nothing. (I wasn't checking OS X because I never needed it.)

**18.04:**

However, 14.04 is nearing EOL date. I've tried both 16.04 and 18.04 and both perform way worse in terms of battery life - the autonomy hit is about ~50% and I can see it in power consumption stats matching what battery status icon is saying - ~10W power usage instead of ~6W on 14.04.

There is no clear indication of what is going on. Powertop does not help, TLP neither.

**Question:**

Does anyone have a similar experience, and maybe a solution for getting 18.04 battery life up to (my) 14.04 levels?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.